# What is causing Serverless deploy error: Unable to validate the following destination configurations, S3 InvalidArgument?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am using the serverless framework to deploy my app.  The end goal is to create an SES receipt rule that captures emails to a certain subdomain and upload them to an S3 bucket.  The object upload will trigger my lambda function.

When trying to deploy my 'serverless.yml', I get the following error:

```
An error occurred: S3BucketEmails - Unable to validate the following 
destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; 
Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: <Request Id>; S3 Extended 
Request ID: <Extended Request Id>.
```

My 'serverless.yml' file:

```
service: <my service name>

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-west-2'}

  environment:
    AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: <my account number>
    SES_WRITABLE_ROLE_NAME: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-ses-writable-role
    SES_WRITABLE_POLICY_NAME: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-ses-writable-policy
    EMAIL_RECEIPT_RULE_NAME: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-receipt-rule
    EMAIL_RECEIPT_RULE_SET_NAME: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-receipt-set-name
    EMAIL_RECEIVED_TABLE_NAME: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-table
    EMAIL_RECEIVED_BUCKET_NAME: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-bucket
    REGION: ${self:provider.region}

  iamRoleStatements:
    -
      Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:CreateTable
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:DeleteTable
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:::${self:provider.environment.EMAIL_RECEIVED_TABLE_NAME}
    - 
      Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:CreateBucket
        - s3:DeleteBucket
        - s3:DeleteObject
        - s3:GetObject
        - s3:PutObject
        - s3:ListBucket
        - s3:PutBucketPolicy
      Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.EMAIL_RECEIVED_BUCKET_NAME}

functions:
  emailReceived:
    handler: emailHandler.emailReceived
    events:
      -
        s3: 
          bucket: emails
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            -
              prefix: emails/

resources:
  Resources:

    S3BucketEmails:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:provider.environment.EMAIL_RECEIVED_BUCKET_NAME}

    SESWritableBucketRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: ${self:provider.environment.SES_WRITABLE_ROLE_NAME}
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - ses.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  aws:Referer: ${self:provider.environment.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: ${self:provider.environment.SES_WRITABLE_POLICY_NAME}
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - s3:*
                  Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.EMAIL_RECEIVED_BUCKET_NAME}
      DependsOn: S3BucketEmails

    MyReceiptRuleSet:
      Type: AWS::SES::ReceiptRuleSet
      Properties:
        RuleSetName: ${self:provider.environment.EMAIL_RECEIPT_RULE_SET_NAME}
      DependsOn: SESWritableBucketRole

    MyReceiptRule:
      Type: AWS::SES::ReceiptRule
      Properties:
        RuleSetName: ${self:provider.environment.EMAIL_RECEIPT_RULE_SET_NAME}
        Rule:
          Name: ${self:provider.environment.EMAIL_RECEIPT_RULE_NAME}
          Enabled: true
          Recipients: 
            -
              subdomain.exampledomain.com
          Actions:
            -
              S3Action:
                BucketName: ${self:provider.environment.EMAIL_RECEIVED_BUCKET_NAME}
                ObjectKeyPrefix: emails/
      DependsOn: MyReceiptRuleSet
```

Before I added the role policy, I was getting an error related to my receipt rule not being able to write to my S3 bucket.  I've only found references of this error when it relates to an [SNS topic](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3/).  However, I don't think this applies to my situation because I'm only uploading the bucket to S3 and not configuring and SNS topic.

Comment: Not necessarily what you're asking about, but the SES ReceiptRule can directly trigger a Lambda, you don't have to do it via an S3 notification. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ses-receiptrule-lambdaaction.html

Comment: @MilanCermak Yes, this is true.  I want to save these received emails for backup purposes, though.

Comment: You'll have both. The `Actions` property of the SES ReceiptRule is a list, so you can define an `LambdaAction` next to your `S3Action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue.  I'll post the code below, but essentially this was a combination of random configuration errors and Cors properties on my bucket.

Because S3 is global, it wasn't being created in the same default region as all of my other resources.  SES needed to access to write to the bucket from another origin, but was not able to because of Cors properties not being set.

I ended up separating my role and policy and changing some minor formatting changes as well.  Here are what my resources and functions now look like.

```
functions:
  emailReceived:
    handler: emailHandler.emailReceived
    events:
      -
        s3: 
          bucket: <my-bucket-name>
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*

resources:
  Resources:

    S3Bucket<My-bucket-name>:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
            -
              AllowedMethods:
                - "PUT"
                - "POST"
                - "GET"
                - "DELETE"
                - "HEAD"
              AllowedOrigins:
                - "*"

    SESWritableBucketPolicy:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
      Properties:
        PolicyName: "SESWritableBucketPolicy"
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Sid: "AllowSESPuts"
              Action: s3:PutObject
              Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket-name>"
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  aws:Referer: "#{AWS::AccountId}"
        Roles: 
          - SESWritableBucketRole
      DependsOn: EmailReceivedLambdaFunction

    SESWritableBucketRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: "SESWritableBucketRole"
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: ses.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  aws:Referer: "#{AWS::AccountId}"
      DependsOn: SESWritableBucketPolicy

    EmailReceivedRuleSet:
      Type: AWS::SES::ReceiptRuleSet
      Properties:
        RuleSetName: "EmailReceivedRuleSet"

    EmailReceivedRule:
      Type: AWS::SES::ReceiptRule
      Properties:
        RuleSetName: "EmailReceivedRuleSet"
        Rule:
          Name: "EmailReceivedRule"
          Enabled: true
          Recipients:
            - "subdomain.domain.com"
          Actions:
            -
              S3Action:
                BucketName: <my-bucket-name>
```

Now we have a working receipt rule on our subdomain.  An S3 bucket that SES can upload emails to when it receives for any email address for a subdomain.  A lambda function that is triggered by uploading an object to that bucket.